# Simple Example of Custom Annotations using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, annotations

I am familiar with the [Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#annotation-classes) about custom annotations, but I am looking for a simple example.

I would like to create an entry in a audit table using an annotation (user, date, action, etc.) when a user creates or updates a widget.

Can you point me to a simple example?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you want to do, this would make it easier to point out a possible example.

Comment: I would like to create an entry in a audit table using an annotation user, date, action, etc.) when a user creates or updates a widget.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/) is a good example of using Symfony2 with Doctrine Common in order to create powerful annotations.

Comment: I don't know if it is sufficient for your needs. Otherwise feel free to explain more concisely your problem and I will provide you more explanations.