# Use customs annotation in a Service

Tags: symfony

I would like to add custom annotation on some service methods

let's imagine :

```
class serviceA
{
  public method1()

  /* @myCustomAnnotation(foo=bar)*/
  public method2()
}

class serviceB
{
  public method101()

  /* @myCustomAnnotation(foo=foo)*/
  public method105()

  /* @myCustomAnnotation(foo=bar)*/
  public method105()
}
```

First of all, Is it possible to do?

How can i specify to my AnnotationServiceListener to listen to method of services?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806176/simple-example-of-custom-annotations-using-symfony2)

Comment: And to save you a click, here's the link from the accepted answer: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/